# How to use Typescript Zod types on a stringified object?

Tags: typescript, schema, zod

I'm quite new with Typescript and `Zod`.
Considering (simplified) `Zod` schema below:

```
export const Event = z
  .object({ 
    ... 
    booking: z
      .array(
        z.discriminatedUnion('type', [
          z.object({ type: z.literal('url'), input: z.string().url() }),
          z.object({ type: z.literal('email'), input: z.string().email() })
        ])
      )
      .transform((t) => JSON.stringify(t))
    ...
  })

export type Event = z.infer<typeof Event>
```

I try to use it somewhere else in my code. For example (simplified again):

```
export const build = (booking : Array<Event['booking']>) => {
  const output = []
  for (const b of booking) {
    if (b.type === 'url') output.push(`abc`)    <-- Error: Property 'input' does not exist on type 'string'
    if (b.type === 'email') output.push(`xyz`)  <-- Error: Property 'input' does not exist on type 'string'
  }
  return output
}
```

I got an error (Property 'input' does not exist on type 'string') and - I think - I understand why:

- My `zod` schema `stringify` my object with `transform`.
- So, indeed, there is no `type` inside a `string`

But how do I get rid of the TS error? Without disabling a rule of course.  Thx.

Comment: Your event is `type Event = {booking: string}` and not `type Event = {booking: {type: string}}`, because whatever it was you transform it into string, what would you expect

Comment: @Dimava Indeed. I've modified my Zod schema but can't understand how to mute some TS errors. I've posted a new question because it's not Zod-related. Thanks.